# Is tf.identity() creating a full deep copy?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm often using the following pattern for managing control flow:

```
with tf.get_default_graph().control_dependencies([c_op]):
     h_state = tf.identity(h_state)
```

However, I'm concerned that tf.identity() might copy the data passed to it which is not what I want. Can somebody confirm that it does or does not create a copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2607cc67f0e4a6cd313399e1f68cc4b9857fe700/tensorflow/core/kernels/identity_op.h#L31) of the `tf.identity()` operation will forward its input to its output without making a deep copy. However, if the `tf.identity()` operation is pinned to a different device from the operation that produces its input, a deep copy *will* occur.